# Eclipse + Git Team Synchronizing is useless

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

We recently have moved from SVN to GIT, and until recently, the problems with the move were if not minimal, at least manageable.

Until a few weeks ago, we just had a single active 'master' branch, which was the old SVN trunk.  But then, we added a branch to do a major upgrade while keeping the master available for bugfixes that could then be easily deployed.

The problem is that as soon as the different project team members started to check stuff in, the Eclipse (Mars 2 with EGit) Team Synchronization perspective started showing stuff as needing to check in that really didnt.

The first time I synchronized, a load of incoming changes came in (the blue arrow) which was unusual as I hadn't seen any since moving to GIT, - we just had to do a PULL instead - so foolishly I accepted them in.  That ended up merging the changes we had put in the trunk with the branch, which we DIDN'T want to do.

Worse, even after pulling in those changes, they still appeared but now as conflicts, even though I accepted them and the files were identical.  Nothing I can do (Mark as Merged, Overwrite, Commit...) gets rid of them.

Anyway, the most unhelpful problem is that now the Team Synchronization brings in hundreds (currently 825!) supposed changed files when I do a synchronize now.  Many of these files are obscure ones that havent changed in years, and are clearly unchanged yet they show up.  Trying to sift through the file list to find what I have actually changed is too much effort, especially as Eclipse helpfully refreshes the list with all the items I removed from the view each time I make any change!

So basically now I am resorting to GitKraken, which has substandard diff tools but at least shows an accurate view of what needs checking in.  Why they decided on the Duplo-sized fonts that take up so much window space in the staging area I have no idea.  And it's SLOW.

I now have a healthy dislike for GIT because its such a faff compared to SVN, although I acknowledge a lot of this is down to the GIT implementation in eclipse.

So, does anyone have any tips about how to get Eclipse to recognize that most of these files shouldn't actually be displayed?  Am I missing some configuration somewhere?  When I right click on the project in eclipse and do Team > Switch To, it correctly shows the branch Im working on, so why is it so inaccurate?  Im using Eclipse Mars2 4.5.2 with JGit 4.6.1

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Well you are running an Eclipse release which is 7 releases out of date and a JGit which is also very out of date. I don't use Git so I can't say if this makes much of a difference,

Comment: The concepts of SVN and Git are very different. Where in SVN you use the _Team Synchronizing_ perspective, in Git you usually use the _Git Stagging_ view.

Comment: What are "most of these files that shouldn't be displayed"? There aren't a lot of specifics here to help give you answers.

Comment: There are many files in the synchronize perspective that just shouldnt be there - files such as old javascript libs and html files that havent been modified in years are popping up in increasing numbers as the branch gets more check-ins that have nothing to do with these files.  Even with running a (reasonably) out of date version of Eclipse, I would have thought such a mature version as v4.6.1 of EGit suggests would not have such a fundamental issue with it.

Comment: OK well to address the issue of old tech, Ive downloaded the latest (2019-06) eclipse and opened the project with that.  Exactly the same thing has happened.  The sync perspective incorrectly says 828 files to check in (when comparing against the branch), GitKraken correctly says 27.  Taking an incorrect file, the eclipse compare view shows that the changes in the file are all whitespace, but the number of space chars on each supposedly different line is equal, so the file shouldnt be marked as different.  I can only think that when the branch was created the files had their encoding changed?

Comment: re: howgler - I do use Git Staging, it usually comes up once you click the Commit option in team sync.  However for the same reasons outlined above, the unstaged changes show many files that I just haven't touched, although fewer (276) than the synchronize perspective.

Comment: @fancyplants Sure, what is displayed in the _Git Staging_ view is different from what is displayed in the _Team Synchronizing_ perspective. They're different things.

Comment: re: howlger - yes but my point is that the staging view is also wrong - just a bit less wrong than the sync perspective.  If my git repo had some sort of problem, I would also expect GitKraken (and now TortoiseGit, which also works fine) to have the same problems, but they don't.  Either its a problem with my configuration of Eclipse EGit, or EGit is just not working right.

Comment: If you use `re: howlger` instead of `@howlger` I will get no notification. If you use also command line Git directly or via a tool indirectly, you have to hit the _Refresh_ button in the _Git Staging_ view to see these changes. Please note, that both your Eclipse and your EGit are pretty old and many releases behind. So I might face issues that have been fixed long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having similar problems with this, I sort of have an answer.

My answer is, that Im not sure what got it working, but my team synchronizing perspective now shows 99% the correct view.  I clicked on various things with increasing desperation to get this to work and then some combination of the below in the Team Synchronizing perspective had the right effect:

- In the Synchronize tab, select the down arrow next to the view type and select either Java Workspace (for the master) or Git Commits (for the branch)
- Click the down arrow next to the Synchronize icon at the far left, select Synchronize and then Git, then select the correct destination (eg ref/heads/master) and then clic on 'Include local uncommitted changes in comparison'

Hopefully thats of help to someone.